# document.getElementById not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason when I call document.getElementById("userGuess").value, the alert box shows nothing when it should show whatever is currently in the text box. I would appreciate any help. Here's my HTML and Javascript portions that are involved:

HTML:

```
<section class="game"> <!-- Guessing Section -->

            <h2 id="feedback">Make your Guess!</h2>

            <form>
                <input type="text" name="userGuess" id="userGuess" class="text" maxlength="3" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter your Guess" required/>
                <input type="submit" id="guessButton" class="button" name="submit" value="Guess"/>
            </form>

            <p>Guess #<span id="count">0</span>!</p>

            <ul id="guessList" class="guessBox clearfix">

            </ul>

        </section>

and Javascript:

alert(document.getElementById("userGuess").value);
```

Comment: The usual reason for this type of code not to work is when you're trying to run the code BEFORE the DOM has loaded and thus when it runs it doesn't find any DOM elements to operate on.  Where is the script run?   Is it in the `<head>` section?  Also, please explain EXACTLY what happens.  "Doesn't work properly" is not an exact description of what happens, what errors show in the console, etc...

Comment: The reason is that your `userGuess` has no value at the time when alert is set. Add value `value="your val"` to the field, or make a function that run the alert when field is filled in

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, the problem isn't with `document.getElementById` at all, it is that your element doesn't actually have a `value` initially and in that case you want to display the text from the `placeholder` attribute instead.

If so, here's how you can do it with jQuery:

```
$("#guessButton").click(function() {
    var $input = $("#userGuess");
    alert($input.val() || $input.attr("placeholder"));
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ratp84gm/

This part: `$input.val() || $input.attr("placeholder")` uses [JavaScript's OR operator `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Description), which returns the first operand if it is truthy, otherwise the second operand. Any non-empty string is considered truthy, so if the user actually has entered a value it will be alerted, otherwise the placeholder text will be alerted.

Or the same thing without jQuery:

```
var input = document.getElementById("userGuess");
alert(input.value || input.placeholder);
// OR
alert(input.value || input.getAttribute("placeholder"));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ratp84gm/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
Try it
<input type="text" name="userGuess" id="userGuess" class="text" maxlength="3" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter your Guess" required value="Guess"/>
```

Comment: *"Try it"* - Try *what*? An explanation would be nice, rather than making everybody compare your code to the original to figure out what you've changed.

Comment: That works, but I was actually trying to make the value dynamic. I assumed the value originally was "Enter your Guess" and wanted to make it so the user could enter values into the textbox, how would I do that?

Comment: your dynamic value set in input value

Answer (score 0):

**Working Ex.**

http://jsfiddle.net/scjdpy8v/

HTML

```
<!-- Guessing Section -->
<section class="game">
    <h2 id="feedback">Make your Guess!</h2>
    <form>
    <input type="text" name="userGuess" id="userGuess" class="text" maxlength="3" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter your Guess" required/>
    <input type="submit" id="guessButton" class="button" name="submit" value="Guess"/>
    </form>
    <p>Guess #<span id="count">0</span>!</p>
    <ul id="guessList" class="guessBox clearfix">
    </ul>
</section>
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
  $('#userGuess').change(function() {
    var userGuess = $(this).val();
    console.log(userGuess);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem might be that you had not set any value to the textbox or if you want to alert in some events then you can write function in the specific events. This will run the script after all DOM has finished loading in the page.

```
 <input type="text" name="userGuess" id="userGuess" class="text" maxlength="3" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter your Guess" value="something" required/>

 $(window).load(function(){
    var text = document.getElementById("userGuess").value;
    alert(text);
 });
```

Comment: The question implies that the code *is* running after the DOM has finished loading, because "the alert box shows nothing" - that is, the alert does appear, whereas if the DOM hadn't loaded trying to access the `.value` property of a non-existent element would give an error.

Comment: I appriciate your answer. The problem might be with the values of textbox which is not set when the DOM has loaded..

Answer (score 0):

Put the alert() method inside an onclick function like so:

```
<section class="game"> <!-- Guessing Section -->

        <h2 id="feedback">Make your Guess!</h2>

        <form>
            <input type="text" name="userGuess" id="userGuess" class="text" maxlength="3" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter your Guess" required/>
            <input onclick="alert(document.getElementById('userGuess').value)" type="submit" id="guessButton" class="button" name="submit" value="Guess"/>
        </form>

        <p>Guess #<span id="count">0</span>!</p>

        <ul id="guessList" class="guessBox clearfix">

        </ul>

    </section>
```

JQuery is unnecessary. Use regular JavaScript.